# Use WP_Query with a custom SQL query

Tags: wp-query, wpdb

To fetch the posts I have a query which includes several joins and is quite complicated to use through WP_Query.

```
SELECT p.post_name, t.name as sname, t2.name as cname FROM wpw0_posts AS p 
INNER JOIN wpw0_term_relationships AS tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id 
INNER JOIN wpw0_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id && tt.taxonomy = 'storylines' 
INNER JOIN wpw0_terms AS t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id 

INNER JOIN wpw0_term_relationships AS tr2 ON p.ID = tr2.object_id 
INNER JOIN wpw0_term_taxonomy AS tt2 ON tr2.term_taxonomy_id = tt2.term_taxonomy_id && tt2.taxonomy = 'company' 
INNER JOIN wpw0_terms AS t2 ON t2.term_id = tt2.term_id 

WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' AND p.post_type = 'post' 
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
```

So I fetched the posts using $wpdb object and get_results() method, but the original template has many WP_Query methods like get_the_post_thumbnail_url(), get_the_category(), etc.

So inorder to use the same template I want to convert the array of posts from

```
$wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

to

```
new WP_Query($args);
```

How can I convert the object or convert the query?

Comment: Why do you want to do this instead of just working with the results of your query?

Comment: Because in order to work with the result, I will have to change the template which will be tedious as its a very big template which uses lots of wp_query methods

Comment: What does your SQL query do? I'm reading it and I see it has something to do with 2 taxonomies, but it's unclear what the goal is. What does it do?

Comment: @TomJNowell It fetches the posts which compulsorily has the 2 taxonomies added to it. There that simple.

Comment: So, you want a `WP_Query` that looks for posts, that have at least 2 terms, one that in taxonomy A, and another in taxonomy B. Where the specific term itself is irrelevant, only that it has terms at all?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you didn't just give the terms a `has_company` and `has_storylines` term? Then you could just look for posts that have those terms, **and it would be significantly faster than your SQL query**, and it would be faster than doing what you're trying to do with `WP_Query`

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes you are right. I'm not aware what is that has_company. Can you explain?

Comment: @TomJNowell Along with has_company(), if the post has a company taxonomy. I would like it as well

Comment: If you have a taxonomy that's hidden, and create a term named `has_company` when a post is saved and it has terms in that taxonomy. It isn't a function, and it isn't something that currently exists, you'd have to build it. It's the equivalent of you making a note saying "This post has terms in that  taxonomy", then checking for the note so the query runs faster

Answer (score 7):

You won't be able to translate a complicated SQL query directly to a WP_Query. What you can do is return Post IDs from the SQL and pass those IDs into the WP_Query args. Do note that this is highly inefficient and will likely create slow queries as `post__in` is not fast.

You need to modify the SQL to include the post ID:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.post_name, /*... etc... */
```

Next we want to tell [`wpdb::get_results()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/) to return an array so we can parse out the IDs:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, ARRAY_A );
```

Next we want to use [`wp_list_pluck()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pluck/) to grab the IDs of the results:

```
$post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $results, 'ID' );
```

Finally, we can pass these IDs into the `posts__in` parameter of WP_Query:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post__in'      => $post_ids,
) );
```

---

If you also want to get the terms you'll need to either get the term slugs or the term IDs.

You need to modify the SQL to include term IDs. Since you have multiple taxonomies you'll need to alias these differently:

```
SELECT /* ... etc... */ t.term_id as storyline_term_id, t2.term_id as company_term_id
```

Next we want to use [`wpdb::get_results()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/) to return an array so we can parse out the term IDs:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, ARRAY_A );
```

Next we want to use [`wp_list_pluck()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pluck/) to grab the term IDs of the results:

```
$story_term_ids = wp_list_pluck( $results, 'storyline_term_id' );
$company_term_ids = wp_list_pluck( $results, 'company_term_id' );
```

Finally, we can get the terms by IDs:

```
$story_terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy'      => 'storylines',
    'object_ids'    => $story_term_ids,
) );
```

Comment: This is okay. I can use this. But there's one more problem. I want the custom taxonomies added to it as well which I'm fetching with sql query "t.name as sname, t2.name as cname" for each post. Can you tell how to get this?

Comment: @SaeeshTendulkar Presumably you can use a similar `wp_list_pluck()` approach if you return those terms IDs or term slugs to the `$results`. Then translate that into a [tax_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters)

Comment: Sorry I did not understand that

Comment: Sorry, I'll have to come back to this later then and submit an edit with an explanation & examples.

Comment: Thank you. I would appreciate it if you could give some explaination.

Comment: @SaeeshTendulkar I realize that a `tax_query` won't matter since we're getting posts by their IDs. I've updated the question to get terms by their IDs.